# Rectangle not showing up

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

Nothing happens on pressing the Button, what I am doing wrong?? I want the Rectangle to be drawn on pressing the button. What's wrong with the code??

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

    class rectangle{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                final JFrame frame=new JFrame("RECTANGLE");
                final JPanel panel=new JPanel();
                JButton button=new JButton("DRAW");
                panel.add(button);
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.setSize(400,400);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                        panel.add(new drawrectangle());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

class drawrectangle extends JComponent{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setPaint(Color.PINK);
        Rectangle2D rect=new Rectangle2D.Double(50,50,200,200);
        g2.draw(rect);
        g2.fill(rect);
    }
}
```

Comment: To the downvoter: This may not be the greatest question ever, but it has a complete, self-contained example that is pretty minimal and shows the problem, and clearly states the expected result (you see a rectangle) and the actual result (you don't see a rectangle).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `repaint()` on your `JFrame`.

```
 button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
              drawrectangle rec= new drawrectangle();
              panel.add(rec);
              rec.paintComponent();
              frame.repaint();
      }
 });
```

Comment: Where: see my edit. Why? Because calling repaint() on any Component will add a request to the repaint manager to paint that component.

Comment: @user3798851 Whoa, calm down there.

Comment: Try my edit. You need to call paintComponent on drawRectangle.

Comment: Try my edit. You need to call paintComponent on drawRectangle.

Comment: @lolkidoki the problem was that the component added to the panel has no size, not that it is not being painted.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write :

```
frame.validate();
frame.repaint();
```

Comment: Your answer in showing up in the Lower Quality Posts review queue due to its short length.  Please consider expanding on your answer to indicate where to add the code you mention and why it will fix the OP's problem.

Comment: @azurefrog It won't, since it is unrelated to the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your component has no size. You need to either override `getPreferredSize()` and return the size of your rectangle, or else you need to set its size in its constructor by calling `setSize()`. The reason your rectangle doesn't appear is because it is drawing outside of its area, and the Java 2D graphics are clipping the portion you are drawing outside the component (that is, all of it).

It is not the case that you need to either call `repaint()` or `validate()` because when you add the rectangle to the panel, it will automatically lay itself out again and mark itself as needing a repaint.

However, be aware that you are adding a new rectangle every time the event fires. Is that what you want? Also, `rectangle` and `drawrectangle` should begin with capital letters to conform to the normal Java naming conventions, although there is also a `java.awt.Rectangle` class, so `Rectangle` might not be the best name to use.

Comment: It worked, thank you :) , can you tell me the use of pack() method??

Comment: The [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) describes it this way: "The pack method sizes the frame so that all its contents are at or above their preferred sizes." The [pack javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack()) says "Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents."

Answer (score 0):

Just add window.visibility to true.